# Calling a number in an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, phone-call

I would like to make an android app that calls the first number in an array and proceeds to the next one once the call is ended. Once the list is exhausted, it stops.
I'm using eclipse and a Sony Ericsson Xperia X10. I've set up the permission to call in the manifest.

Comment: "call" = "make a phone call"?

Comment: This article may be helpful [Android:make a call](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-make-a-phone-call-in-android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write service to check if current call is ended or not.
after disconnection of one call you can dial next number from your array in **onRecieve** method of **BroadcastReceiver**.

code to check call is disconnected or not.

```
     switch(state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("Call","Outgoing Call finished");
        break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("Call","Outgoing Call Starting");
        break;
    }
```